# how to stretch ik bone in blender 2.8

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

in blender 2.7 we have Autostretch Ik for stretching ik and not stretching it, but I can't find it in 2.8.

I want this result: please see the picture.[image]

Comment: What is this *autostretch* you mention? josh's answer gives me the desired result in Blender 2.79 and 2.8. I can't see any difference.

Comment: what I want is, If i drag leg or hand it should stretch and get longer as much as I want. I want to use like squash and stretch

Answer (score 3):

Select the bone you want to stretch and set its amount of stretch. The amount is calculated in relation to other bones which have some, so if only one bone has some stretch, even a little value leads to a total stretch.

[image]

If you want a "Squash and stretch" behaviour you can duplicate the lower leg bone, put off the IK constraint, add a copy loc constraint pointing at the IK constrainded bone and then add a stretch to constraint, pointing at the ik controller (foot) bone. Set the IK bone as non deforming, and use the stretch to instead.

[image]

Comment: I need like squash and stretch, but this option you showed scales it and makes it bigger. what I want is just stretch it

Comment: Then you should use a "Stretch to" constraint, instead of IK.

Comment: Updated the answer